# Issue submitting a pull request

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging, pull-request

I'm trying to submit a pull request of a branch and merge it back its parent branch, but the pull request shows changes as if I'm committing back to the master (where the parent branch is branched from).

For example, suppose I have a branch (call it `B`) based off of master (call it `M`). In `B` I create a file called `README.md`. That file is empty. I add one line to `README.md` in `B`, commit, and push those changes to `B`. Then I create a branch off of `B` (call it `T`), add a line to `README.md`, commit, and push those changes to `T`.

```
M
  \
   B (README.md - add one line)
     \
      T (README.md - add another line)
```

The issue I'm encountering is that when I submit a pull request to merge `T` back into `B`, the changes that are shown indicate that I'm adding the whole file of `README.md` and not the one line change I was expecting (the diff between changes in T and the latest in B).

I'm not sure how this happened. Have you encountered this before and if so, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: Do you maybe have a link you can share to this pull request?

Comment: Sorry, I can't share it. The code is work related.

Comment: Your example is a bit contrived because there are only two lines in this case.  My guess is that the actual diff shows that you are deleting the entire contents of the file and then adding back the new content.  Git's diff tool isn't always perfect.  The problem may be that the two lines in question are adjacent.

Comment: Then can you try to reproduce this in a new public repository?

Comment: @poke I tried doing this in a new repo but didn't encounter the issue.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen These are separate lines. The example's the simplest representation of the issue I'm seeing right now with the branch I'm working on. I wonder if it's some type of history/timestamp where I forced some type of fast-forward.

Comment: Then how exactly are we supposed to help you if even *you* cannot reproduce the issue?

Comment: I understand the reproducibility of this is low. Sorry I'm not able to provide more details at the moment. I'm posting this here to see if others have encountered a similar issue, and to ask what they did to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

A pull request includes two branches: base branch and compare branch. I am sure you use M as the base branch and T as the compare branch, so you see the change of adding the whole file from the pull request. 
If you want get the change only including the another line, you can cherry-pick T to M and create a new pull request.

Comment: In github, I made sure I had picked T compared to B before submitting the pull request.